# "AppleARMPMUCharger" no longer exports Battery Information/Diagnostics when run via idevicediagnostics.exe prior to iOS 12

Tags: ios, ios12, libimobiledevice

Up until iOS 11, i've been using the idevice** binaries to extract information from iPhones ranging from models 6 to X via `idevicediagnostics.exe` on `Windows OS` via `idevicediagnostics ioreg AppleARMPMUCharger`.

However, with the release of iOS 12, everything stopped working. What once was a [lively file](https://pastebin.com/DyQ90RgH) (converted to JSON) i get to export from this command is now an [empty xml document](https://pastebin.com/KJ3tnLwc). Now i do this because of our Company's Business. We extract battery information as insurance, proof, and history that batteries are as good as they can be. Also to track the Battery Serial and SOH Value while at it.

I've downloaded several updated idevice** binaries and even updated iTunes and Apple drivers but as i'd expect, its broken now. Now, i am looking for alternative ways to do this, are there any other API out there that can do the same job as AppleARMPMUCharger once did? I'm thinking of working on a small iOS Application that will export the data from within the iPhone itself and send it to an FTP or REST API maybe? However, i do not know which registry or namespace to hook it up to.

It's worth noting that CoconutBattery - a MacOS Application that also reads battery information from iPhone still works as expected. Leaving me wonder, how they do it, or what API they are looking at.

Looking for positive responses, cheers.

*PS: links routes to the actual files exported when the command is ran.*

Answer (score 0):

I had one similar problem which was solved finally by reinstalling the libmobiledevice. I found the instructions from [this Github issue](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/717#issuecomment-430622355). I am posting those instructions here as well for convenience.

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
sudo rm /var/db/lockdown/*
brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
brew unlink usbmuxd
brew link usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller
```

If you do not have brew installed in your machine, please follow the instruction from [this website](https://brew.sh/).

Hence, finally, the reinstallation of libmobiledevice solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to get information using the `AppleSmartBattery` key instead? See [libimobiledevice#823](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/823)